# Cheap gimbal and action camera for hexacopter

Tags: camera

I am looking for a cheap gimbal and action camera

For the action camera, I would like it to be capable of...

- 4K or 1080p recording
- recording a live output to a fpv transmitter, just like Gopro
- recording 4K or 1080p to an SD card while outputting a live (slightly lower) resolution of fpv footage to a transmitter
- I would like it to be cheap, so if it does break, I could easily buy another one

For the gimbal...

- It needs to stabilise very well
- 2 axis OR 3 axis if it’s below around £50
- Must keep vibrations dampened enough to not be seen

Thanks,

Sid

Comment: What price range do you consider cheap for a camera?

Comment: @Richard Chambers - around £30